# How to add cocoa framework  to my in iphone application

Tags: iphone

Thanks in advance .

How to add Cocoa framework into my iphone application.If i include also it is giving an error . Because I have downloaded an iphone app. It has imported

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#endif
```

like this. If i try to execute it is giving an error .I have downloaded app from http://www.macresearch.org/tutorial-intro-core-animation in that side heading "Let's Animate..."

If any one know please help me.

Comment: What framework you're trying to add and how? And what errors do you get? Also Cocoa is a **Mac** technology, iOS uses **Cocoa-touch**

Answer (score 1):

The app you've downloaded is a Mac app, not an iPhone app. You won't be able to run it on the iPhone.

Comment: Thank u for ur response. I don't know the difference between mac app and iphone app. Will u provide some information about it. And how can i execute it in macbook.

Comment: To run it, just open the Xcode project, and hit "Build and Run". You don't need to change any other settings. As regards the difference, Mac apps use AppKit where iPhone apps use UIKit. In practice it means that any code that relates to the user interface can only be used on either Mac or iPhone, not both.

Comment: yes Cocoa.framework is there and BaseSdk is 10.5. But my mac version is 10.6.3. Is the version problam here.